# Changing Azure VM ip address without downtime

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, ip-address

I have an Azure VM with SQL Server on. There are a number of applications using this database via it's public ip address. The ip address is currently set to Dynamic and the VM requires maintenance which could change it. Is there a way of assigning a static ip address to the VM while keeping the current one active while I update the applications to use the new static one?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a static public IP address, not change it to another IP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way of assigning a static ip address to the VM while
>   keeping the current one active while I update the applications to use
>   the new static one?

If I understand it correctly, you just want to change the public IP address to static.

We can change the public IP address to static via Azure portal, that IP address will not change.

Comment: Thanks. If I change the current IP address to static will it assign a new static ip or keep the existing one and make it static?

Comment: keep the existing one and make it static.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the existing IP address to Static, carried out the maintenance plan and when it came back up the IP address persisted.